# Underfull \vbox (badness 1000 in tabularx with automatic adjustment of breaks in the text

Tags: tabularx

this is my first post here. Although I use (or try to) Latex for a while, I am a beginner and I am struggling with basic stuff. I read other solutions for the type of problem I am having and I still cannot solve it.

I am getting a warning whenever I use \tabularx. The main problem is that it seems to be messing up with the number of the tables as well.

I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage[margin=20pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
    \caption{Treatment's description.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable} \textbf{(Type)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description} \textbf{(States)}} 
\endhead    
       \midrule 
%
Treatment (Labelled)&
The treatment used during the pregnancy: None for GDM negative people, Diet for GDM positive people that never had any medication to control BGL during pregnancy and Medication for GDM positive people that had medication at any point during the pregnancy. (None, Diet and Medication)\\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:treatmenttable}%
\end{table}%

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
    \caption{Signs' description.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable} \textbf{(Type)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description} \textbf{(States)}} 
\endhead    
       \midrule 
%
%
BGL before 20 weeks (Labelled) & Blood glucose level before 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\
BGL after 20 weeks (Labelled) & Blood glucose level after 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:signstable}%

\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Warnings like `Underfull \vbox (badness 1000)` can be ignored without much affecting your output-- so far as my experience goes.

Comment: What is `\endhead` doing inside your `tabularx`? `\endhead` is usually only used in tables that span multiple pages, such as ones that are created using `longtable` or `xltabular`. Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also explain what "messing up with the number of the tables" means specifically. What kind of numbering do you expect instead of the one you currently get?

Comment: Laslt,y there is a `\\ ` missing at the end of your header row and right before the following `\midrule`.

Comment: Problem, which you faced is use of `ltablex` package. Since your tables is inside of `table` float, you not need this package (which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx`. In preamble add `tabularx` packag, remove `ltablex` package and command `\endhead` from tables codes. After this you will get desired result. Instead `ltablex` i suggest to use `xltabular` or recent version of `tabularray` . BTW, from preamble remove all duplicate loaded packages.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problems and cure for them are explained in comments below your question.

However, your problems can be avoided by us of the `tabularray` package in your document. Tables written by it, using `X[...]` column types behave similar as `tabularx` tables. Followed MWE works with `tabullarray` package version 2021P or newest:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text


\begin{document}

\section{Test}
Use of \verb+booktabs+ table environment as defined in the \verb+tabularray+ package:
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Treatment's description.}
    \label{tab:treatmenttable}
\begin{booktabs}{colspec = X[l] X[j],
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},
                }
    \toprule
Variable (Type) & Description (States)  \\
    \midrule
Treatment (Labelled)
    &   The treatment used during the pregnancy: None for GDM negative people, Diet for GDM positive people that never had any medication to control BGL during pregnancy and Medication for GDM positive people that had medication at any point during the pregnancy. (None, Diet and Medication)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
    \end{table}
    
Use of \verb+longtblr+ table environment as defined in the \verb+tabularray+ package:

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Signs’ description.},
  label = {tab:signstable},
                ]{colspec = l X[j],
                  rowhead=1, 
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},
                }
    \toprule
Variable (Type) & Description (States)  \\
    \midrule
BGL before 20 weeks (Labelled) & Blood glucose level before 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\
BGL after 20 weeks (Labelled)  & Blood glucose level after 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\
    \midrule
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[65]    \\
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[66]    \\
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[67]    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum:**
Of course you can use classic tables packages. For example use of the  `xltabular` also gives desired document format.  A tables codes are abit longer as at `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text


\begin{document}

\section{Test}
Use of \verb+tabularx+ table environment which is loaded by \verb+xltabular+ package:
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Treatment's description.}
    \label{tab:treatmenttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variable (Type)}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Description (States)}}  \\
    \midrule
Treatment (Labelled)
    &   The treatment used during the pregnancy: None for GDM negative people, Diet for GDM positive people that never had any medication to control BGL during pregnancy and Medication for GDM positive people that had medication at any point during the pregnancy. (None, Diet and Medication)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
Use of \verb+xltabular+ table environment:

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lX}
\caption{Signs’ description.}
\label = {tab:signstable}\\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variable (Type)}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Description (States)}}  \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Signs’ description (cont.).} \\
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variable (Type)}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Description (States)}}  \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body
BGL before 20 weeks (Labelled) & Blood glucose level before 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\
BGL after 20 weeks (Labelled)  & Blood glucose level after 20 weeks. (Normal, Abnormal) \\
    \midrule
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[65]    \\
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[66]    \\
just dummy filler               & \lipsum[67]    \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Result is(almost) the same as before.